# laravel admin panel driver status

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm developing an admin panel for taxi booking.For that in driver module admin should approve/disapprove the driver who get registered.In which admin **get notify** if any driver registered and then admin can **approve/disapprove**.Drivers who get approved goes to drivers table and who are all disapproved go to rejected table.I've to achieve this through laravel.Can anybody give some technical idea for this?

```
<div ><a href="{!! route('approve', ['id' => $user->id]) !!}"><img alt="" src="http://school.glwh.org/wp-content/uploads/bigstock-vector-green-positive-checkmar-16955600.jpg" 
        style="height: 30px; width: 20px" ></img></a>
        <a href="{!! route('reject', ['id' => $user->id]) !!}"><img alt="" 
src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/1/9/2/12065738771352376078Arnoud999_
   Right_or_wrong_5.svg.hi.png" 
        style="height: 20px; width: 20px" ></img></a></div>
```

In controller for approve,

```
public function postApprove($id)
{
     $application = Move::where('id', '=', e($id))->first();
if($application)
{
    $application->approved = 1;
    $application->save();
  return redirect()->route('driver');
}
}
```

For reject,

```
public function postreject($id)
{
     $application = Move::where('id', '=', e($id))->first();
if($application)
{
    $application->approved =0;
    $application->save();
  return redirect()->route('driver');
}
}
```

Comment: I've made it onclick "approve"  driver status will be 1.But I want to know what should I use in laravel to achieve if approved goes to one table else disapproved goes to another table

Comment: Code sir..... Paste your code here....

Comment: I've updated my code now.In this function can I make insert/delete operations to a table

Comment: @GyandeepSharma I've updated my code